# What are the limitations of docker swarm over kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-swarm

I need to make a decision for container orchestration , and needed help in finding out limitation in real world scenarios that can occur using docker swarm over kubernetes, if anyone ever faced any such limitation please suggest.

*The containers cluster may reach a value of approx 50-100 containers.*

Comment: In case this interests you, you can check the other way around. For example swarm is rather developed in regarding secret management and distribution between nodes, whereas Kubernetes seems to still to distribute secrets in plain text when using etcd. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/12742. This may be important to you.

Answer (score 1):

Docker swarm is young and there are a lot of features introduced relatively quickly. This however causes more issues and open "serious" bugs. For a production system that should be up 100% that might be an issue. I personally experienced [a bug](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31698) that made it impossible to start new containers because they were assigned an IP that is already taken. This forced me to shut down my swarm (it's a dev system so I didn't mind too much).

I suggest having a look at [the most commented swarm bugs/issues](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues?q=is%3Aopen+label%3Aarea%2Fswarm+sort%3Acomments-desc) in github.

Comment: Thanks @herm  and does _Starting container failed_ issue still persist in newer version of docker swarm.

Comment: As you see in github the issue is open since march so it still exists. I experienced it on the version 17.06.
If you want to find some differences in the features look into what options you have for load balancing and what rules you can use (constraints) when it comes to runing your services. I think in kubernetes you can define a group of services that are a "package" to be deployed on the same (but an arbitrary) machine. That's not possible in swarm.